# ad hoc builds install team provisioning profile

Tags: ipad, provisioning, adhoc

When I install an ad hoc build of my ipad app, I notice that I get both the ad hoc provisioning file *and* a "team provisioning profile" showing up on my ipad.  I've only ever dragged the ad hoc provisioning file to my itunes and am trying to debug why for a while I had an error showing up when I was syncing the app, something about a signer not being valid.

Does anyone know what makes this team provision file get added and either 1) how I can prevent it from being added so I can debug the adhoc provision file itself or 2) if this team provision file is normal and how things work now with ad hoc builds?  It shows up when I install it from my mac where I develop the app and also on a secondary mac where I don't develop the app so it doesn't seem to be something xcode is sticking on the ipad during debug builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode automatically installs the Team Provisioning Profile onto the device, if it is registered to your account as a development device.

This profile is only used for apps build using the debug Xcode configuration. AdHoc builds are not signed with this profile but using the AdHoc profile. So those two profiles to not interfere.

The signer error usually means that the provisioning profile, which the app is requiring, is not installed on the device and the profile being inside the app doesn't have the device listed.